# integrate an UML modeling Tool in my plugin?

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, tool-uml, papyrus

I'm developing a plugin eclipse that generates code from a UML diagram. I want to integrate the tool making these UML diagrams in my plugin. I explain : I want to have a button or a menu that contains " create a new UML diagram". By clicking on it, the tool's editor ( papyrus for example ) shows up so I can create my diagram.

Is it possible ? I admit I am new in developing plugins. And if it is, how ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  this should be straightforward.  You can use an Eclipse model-to-text templating technology like M2T-JET to easily generate the file containing the new model and to easily generate code from that model.  Once the model file is created and populated with initial content, use the IDE class to open the default editor on the file.